# SmartGit (git) ghost modifications

Tags: c++, linux, git, smartgit

I currently use smartgit for a personal project.

I have text (.txt) + code (C++) in my repo. Each time I modify my text files and commit them, "ghost" changes automatically appear in my .h and .cpp files.

SmartGit shows modifications but when I check I compare the versions SmartGit says the content of the 2 versions is equal.

I guess this is related to me using both Linux and Windows but I cannot find how to solve the issue. I have looked on the internet but could find no clear answer.

Comment: What do `git status` and `git diff` show for this repository?

Comment: I believe YSC got it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the line ending being different on Windows (`\r\n`) and Linux (`\n`). To fix it, set the `core.autocrlf` option of git.

From the [Github help page](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) for handling this issue:

> The `git config core.autocrlf` command is used to change how Git handles line endings. It takes a single argument.
>
> On Windows, you simply pass true to the configuration. For example:
>
> ```
> git config --global core.autocrlf true
> # Configure Git on Windows to properly handle line endings
> ```